# Did "[@attribute='value']" mean something in old jQuery attribute filter?

Tags: jquery

I'm migrating a "not mine" very old code from `jQuery 1.4` to `jQuery 1.9`.

I've got an error here:

```
var p = $("input[@name='project[]']").serialize();
```

But I'm not sure if it's a typo ignored in old jQuery version, or it's a deprecated syntax. I don't see anything in doc and I wouldn't break any application logic.

Someone has memory of this?

The error is obviously:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@name='project[]']

Comment: Yup. Used to work, deprecated.

Comment: `Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.`

Comment: @ShadowWizard do'h. Searching with wrong keywords. Thanks

Comment: @chumkiu [this was my search string](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+%22%40name%22) - second result is a bingo. :-)

Comment: yup. Because I did not think it was related directly with `name`

Comment: @chumkiu: Well, it's not!